# How to concat while converting a map into an array in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a currency map file like this:

`currency.js` which has currencies in an object which looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  'United States': 'USD',
  'India': 'Rupee',
  'Mexico': 'Peso',
}
```

And my code looked like this:

```
'use strict';


const React = require('react');
const currency = require('js/legacy/core/models/countries');

const RegistrationCountryField = ({onCurrencyNameSet, currencyName}) => {
    const currencyNames = ['Select Currency'].concat(Object.values(currency));
    const currencyOptions = function(currencyName) {
        return <option value={currencyName}>{currencyName}</option>;
    };
    return (
        <fieldset className="form-group">
            <label className="group-label">Country</label>
            <select onChange={onCurrenctNameSet} className="form-group-control" value={currency}>
                {countryNames.map(currencyOptions)}
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    );
};
```

However, Object.values was not supported and I had to use Object.keys. So code looked like this:

```
const currencyOptions = Object.keys(currency).map((currenyCode) =>
    <option key={currencies[currenyCode]}>{countries[currenyCode]}</option>
);
```

My question is 'How do i append select currency' in the last code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `array.map` returns a new array, and since array methods can be chained, you can just do this:

```
const currencyOptions = Object.keys(currency).map((currenyCode) =>
  <option key={currencies[currenyCode]}>{countries[currenyCode]}</option>
)
.concat(
  <option key="selectOption">Select currency</option>
);
```

or if you want the select-currency option to be first, you can reverse it:

```
const currencyOptions = 
  [<option key="selectOption">Select currency</option>] // array of length 1
  .concat(Object.keys(currency).map((currenyCode) =>
    <option key={currencies[currenyCode]}>{countries[currenyCode]}</option>
  );
```

or use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
const currencyOptions = [
  <option key="selectOption">Select currency</option>,
  ...Object.keys(currency).map((currenyCode) =>
<option key={currencies[currenyCode]}>{countries[currenyCode]}</option>
];
```